# Push notification FCM no se ejecuta cuando no se encuentra abierto el Fragment que lo contiene

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tengo un código de Push notification que se activa cuando uno de los datos en mi Databade de Firebase cambia. El código funciona perfectamente cuando me encuentro dentro del Fragment donde está incorporado, pero cuando cierro la app o cambio de Fragment o Activity este deja de funcionar...

¿Cuál puede ser el problema?... Cuando envío las notificaciones desde la plataforma de Firebase no hay problemas, las notificaciones me llegan aunque este cerrada la aplicación, pero cuando trabajo con el código dentro de este Fragment no es lo mismo, sólo funciona siempre y cuando este abierta la aplicación y se encuentre en el Fragment que contiene el código.

Este es el código que esta implementado y que ejecuta la notificación cuando cambia algún valor en la Database

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                    Iterator<DataSnapshot> items = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                                                    entries.clear();
                                                    while (items.hasNext()) {
                                                        DataSnapshot item = items.next();
                                                        log = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                                                        txtlogactual.setText(log + "");

                                                        int aviso5 = Integer.parseInt(Numero5) - 5;
                                                        int aviso1 = Integer.parseInt(Numero5) - 1;

                                                        if (getActivity() != null) {

                                                            new TextoParpadeante(getActivity(), txtlogactual);

                                                            if (aviso5 == log) {
                                                                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                                                String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";

                                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                                                    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);

                                                                    // Configure the notification channel.
                                                                    notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
                                                                    notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                                                                    notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                                                                    notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                                                                    notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
                                                                    notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                                                                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
                                                                }

                                                                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

                                                                notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                                                                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                                                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alerta)
                                                                        .setTicker("Hearty365")
                                                                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                                                                        .setContentTitle("Aviso")
                                                                        .setContentText("¡Ingresa ahora!")
                                                                        .setContentInfo("Info");

                                                                notificationManager.notify(/*notification id*/1, notificationBuilder.build());
                                                            }

                                                            if (aviso1 == log) {
                                                                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                                                String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";

                                                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                                                    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);

                                                                    // Configure the notification channel.
                                                                    notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
                                                                    notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                                                                    notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                                                                    notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                                                                    notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
                                                                    notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                                                                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
                                                                }

                                                                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

                                                                notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                                                                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                                                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alerta)
                                                                        .setTicker("Hearty365")
                                                                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                                                                        .setContentTitle("Aviso")
                                                                        .setContentText("¡Ingresa ahora!")
                                                                        .setContentInfo("Info");

                                                                notificationManager.notify(/*notification id*/1, notificationBuilder.build());
                                                            }

                                                        }
```

¿Cuál podría ser el problema?

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda!

Comment: en donde estas ejecutando este codigo en el fragment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando te referis a un push notifications que se activa cuando cambias algo desde firebase, y este lo hace solo cuando tu app esta abierta, es por que no es un push notification, sino que es una notificacion local que creas con el `NotificationManager`  , una push notification es la que mandas a travez de la consola de firebase.

Lo que te esta sucediendo es que mientras estas en el Fragment, el listener que escucha a tu base de datos permanece activo para avisarle al `NotificationManager` que debe crear una notificacion cuando cambia algo en la base de datos.

Lo que podrias hacer es usar un servicio de background que este escuchando el cambio de tu base de datos y ejecute el `NotificationManager` para mostrarte la notificacion. Podes leer un poco mas [en este link](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service)

Un snippet que te puede servir es el siguiente para poder hacerlo

```
 public class ChildEventListener extends Service {
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            //Añadis el eventListener a firebase               
            Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("FirebaseURL");
            myFirebaseRef.child("REFERENCIA").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    //llama a la creacion de las notificaciones aca
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
                    Log.e("The read failed: ", error.getMessage());
                }
            });

          }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    Log.e("The read failed: ", firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });

            return START_STICKY;
       }

  }
```

recorda registrar el servicio en el manifest

```
 <service android:name=".ChildEventListener "/>
```

Hay dos razones por las que el sistema puede ejecutar un servicio. Si alguien llama a `Context.startService()`, el sistema recuperará el servicio (creándolo y llamando a su método `onCreate()` si es necesario) y luego llamará a su método `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)` con los argumentos suministrados por el cliente.

Para los servicios iniciados, existen dos modos de operación principales adicionales en los que pueden decidirse ejecutar, según el valor que devuelven desde `onStartCommand(): START_STICKY` se usa para servicios que se inician y detienen explícitamente según sea necesario.

Algo a tener en cuenta es que si el sistema se va quedando con poca memoria, puede ser que el mismo OS de Android te mate el servicio para ahorrar espacio ya que no se persive como un servicio utilizable.

Comment: Estoy intentando implementarlo, el problema que tengo es que agregar el eventlistener de firebase es un código gigante y que tiene varios textview que no están creados en esta clase...

Comment: Perfecto amigo, tuve que inflar los layout del fragment para poder leer algunas variables desde el fragment y así funciono muy bien. Gracias por tu ayuda.